# Handling optional query params in API and Database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

I am working on a .Net core API and have a paged endpoint that can take optional query params. For example, the endpoint lists items and you can also specify to filter on fields either containing or equaling a certain value.

https://endpoint/items?pageparams=pageData&field1Contains=value&field1Equals=value&field2Contains=value&field2Equals=value

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthSchemes)]
[Route("items")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPagedItems(
      [FromQuery] PageParameters pageParameters, 
      [FromQuery] OptionalSearchParams searchParameters)
{
      // logic
}
```

At the moment I am treating contains as higher-order than equals, so if you pass both 'equals' and 'contains' for the same field, 'contains' will be applied and 'equals' ignored.

The API is also building the query and where clause dynamically which I really don't want to for obvious security reasons.

```
 var searchClauses = new List<string>();

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchParameters.Field1Contains))
 {
      searchClauses.Add($" ([Field1] LIKE '%{searchParameters.Field1Contains}%')");
 }
 else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchParameters.Field1Equals))
 {
      searchClauses.Add($" ([Field1] = '{searchParameters.Field1Equals}') ");
 }
 // logic to read other optional params and add where clauses to list

 var query = @$"SELECT TOP {pageParameters.PageSize} 
                -- statement removed for brevity --
                FROM [SomeTable]
                ORDER BY [Field]
                OFFSET {((pageParameters.PageNumber - 1) * pageParameters.PageSize)} ROW) 
                    BASE 
                WHERE {string.Join(" AND ", searchClauses)}
```

The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to pass these values to the database as parameters/stored procedures as they will not always be used and there is logic to apply based on precedence. Not entirely true...I did manage to build an SQL query but it is bulky and has way too many nested case/select statements in the where clause which would be a nightmare to maintain/performance impact.

Is there a better way of handling optional field filters while also paging in a parametrized way? I really don't want to grab every item from the DB and then filter as there is potential to be thousands of items returned.

Comment: You c# code should have a list of ALL parameters and type (int, varchar,...). Then depending on which parameters the user selects you can select items from the list.  To make more generic you can use the method GetSchema which will get the tables, columns, types from the SQL database.

Comment: Not quite what I'm after, yes all fields and types are know but I cannot pick and chose what params i pass a stored procedure, they are concrete. I also need to alter based on contains/equals requirements.

Comment: An input parameter in sql server can be null.  So in store procedure you can test input parameters for null and either set to a default value or ignore.

Comment: @MattSykes, A must read: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by  Erland Sommarskog. I personally use Static SQL with OPTION (RECOMPILE) a lot in my system.

Answer (score 0):

The reading specified by Vladimir pointed me in the best direction, specifically dynamic sql generated by the procedure itself and then executed. See http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html#paramquery